# django raises syntax error in server although it works on localhost

Tags: django, django-models, syntax-error, mod-wsgi

I am using mod_wsgi and virtualenv and running a django application.
However, it raises and interesting syntax error. Although it is running on my local, it didn't run at server.

```
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
 mod_wsgi (pid=29322): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/myproject/django.wsgi'.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/sin/django_projects/webapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 272, in __call__
     response = self.get_response(request)
   File "/home/sin/django_projects/webapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 169, in get_response
     response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
   File "/home/sin/django_projects/webapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 214, in handle_uncaught_exception
     if resolver.urlconf_module is None:
   File "/home/sin/django_projects/webapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 274, in _get_urlconf_module
     self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
   File "/home/sin/django_projects/webapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
     __import__(name)
   File "/home/sin/django_projects/myproject/urls.py", line 8, in ?
     admin.autodiscover()
   File "/home/sin/django_projects/webapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 26, in autodiscover
     import_module('%s.admin' % app)
   File "/home/sin/django_projects/webapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
     __import__(name)
   File "/home/sin/django_projects/myproject/userprofile/admin.py", line 1, in ?
     from myproject.companyreview.models import ReviewRate
   File "/home/sin/django_projects/myproject/companyreview/models.py", line 9
      class CommentStatus():
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

**companyreview model**

```
class CommentStatus():
    PENDING = 0
    CONFIRMED = 1
    DELETED = 2
```

**django.wsgi**

```
import os
import sys
import site

vepath = '/home/sin/django_projects/webapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages'
site.addsitedir(vepath)

os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/tmp'

sys.path.append('/home/sin/django_projects/')
sys.path.append('/home/sin/django_projects/myproject/')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

I suspect the python versions because if there were a syntax error, it won't run in local. What may cause such a silly error?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Versions of Python older than 2.5 do not accept an empty base list. Either derive from `object` or remove the parens.

```
class CommentStatus(object):
```

Comment: Then the problem is related with libraries. As you see from in the log, django installed in my virtual env. However, for some reason it still dpends on python2.4 which is default in CentOS. How can I resolve it?